# Replace selection in one movement

Tags: spacemacs, selection

I'm getting started using spacemacs with vim bindings for editing and one thing I would like to do sometimes is replace some text with some other text.  For example I might have

```
k x = (1 + 1) * x
```

and I want to select replace `(1 + 1)` with `2`.  Normally in vim I would just type `f(v%s2<Esc>`.

However in spacemacs `s` doesn't work on selections like it does in vim, this instead puts `2` around the selection

```
k x = 2(1 + 1)2 * x
```

Which is not what I wanted.  (Strangely `s` seems to work perfectly in normal mode)

Now obviously in this case I can just do `di` to delete and enter insert mode separately but in general `di` has some important drawbacks:

- It cannot be repeated across several lines using visual selection mode (a very common use case)
- It cannot be repeated with `.` since it is two actions.

Is there another option that I could use to achieve the functionality of my old `s`?  Or do I have to modify my configs somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just preface this by saying that I am not very familiar with spacemacs except for the fact that it is similar to vim so I might be missing emacsy solutions. That being said, a friend of mine who uses spacemacs tested these suggestions for me and has confirmed that they work.

---

You can just use the exact sequence you have been using but replace the `s` with a `c`.
(As in `f(v%c2<Esc>`). You can also achieve the same effect without visual mode with the `c` command with the motion `ab` which is the motion over the whole of a parenthetical. Combined with the `f` command to reach the start of the parenthetical the whole set of commands would be `f(cab2<Esc>`.